# unable to parse json array with in json object

Tags: android, json, listview

i am not able to read json data and bind into list view in andord.list view is display but values of doctype is always shows with v4.could you tell me what i did wrong with code.i am attaching code of parsing json data.

```
[
{
id: "HT20140109105317640",
basePath: "D:\img",
lstDocType: [
{
doctype: "PP1",
imageName: "CH100610_002_003_PP1.jpg",
imageupload: false
},
{
doctype: "PP2",
imageName: "CH100610_002_003_PP2.jpg",
imageupload: false
},
{
doctype: "V1",
imageName: "CH100610_002_003_V1.jpg",
imageupload: false
},
{
doctype: "V2",
imageName: "CH100610_002_003_V2.jpg",
imageupload: false
},
{
doctype: "V3",
imageName: "CH100610_002_003_V3.jpg",
imageupload: false
},
{
doctype: "V4",
imageName: "CH100610_002_003_V4.jpg",
imageupload: false
}
],
f_FNAME: "SANJAY",
f_FORM: "002",
f_TCD: "CH100610",
f_TNO: "003",
f_LNAME: "NANKANI"
},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{}
]
```

Here is code of parsing json data

```
public class DisplayList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pd.setMessage("Please Wait List Is Loading");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try
            {
                // create instance of json data class
                TourList tl=new TourList();
                jarray=tl.getJsonFromUrl("http://192.168.1.239:8080/VisaDocUpload/historycon/selectbycount/0/10");
                for(int i=0;i<jarray.length();i++)
                {
                    HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
                    JSONObject c=jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    id=c.getString(KEY_ID);

                    JSONArray doct=c.getJSONArray("lstDocType");
                    for(int j=0;j<doct.length();j++)
                    {
                        JSONObject jo=doct.getJSONObject(j);
                        doctype=jo.getString(KEY_DOCTYPE);


                    }

                    map.put(KEY_ID,id);
                    map.put(KEY_DOCTYPE,doctype);
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }



            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("In Back","");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pd.dismiss();
            lv.setAdapter(new MyTourDisplay(MainActivity.this,arraylist));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+id+doctype,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parsing is correct, the problem is related to the fact that you are only assigning doctype inside the more inner for loop so, inside the map, you are putting the last value you assign to doctype

```
private class Holder {
  public ArrayList<String>() docLst;
  // possible more kind of elements
}
```

and then:

```
Holder holder = new Holder();  
holder.docLst = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int j=0;j<doct.length();j++) {
     JSONObject jo=doct.getJSONObject(j);
     doctype=jo.getString(KEY_DOCTYPE);
     holder.docLst.add(doctype);
 }

 map.put(id, holder);
```

of course your HashMap have to be of the type `<String, Holder>`

Comment: did you put map.put(KEY_ID,id); ? If you did it does not serve because you are adding different elements with the same key, and keys are unique in map. Just tell me what you wanna achieve

Comment: i want to display doctype values but it shows v4 values to the doctype.but value of doctype is different for each position.it shows only last position values

Comment: That's clear. One thing that you can do is to have a collection for KEY_ID, and add the elements to that collection

Comment: I edited my answer with some hint. But of course lot depends on how you structured your code

Answer (score 0):

Use this format of JSON  :

```
  {
     "array" : [
    {
    id: "HT20140109105317640",
    basePath: "D:\img",
    lstDocType: [
           {
            doctype: "PP1",
            imageName: "CH100610_002_003_PP1.jpg",
            imageupload: false
            },
            {
            doctype: "PP2",
            imageName: "CH100610_002_003_PP2.jpg",
            imageupload: false
            }
         ]
     }
    ]
}
```

Then proceed like this :

```
    json=tl.getJsonFromUrl("http://192.168.1.239:8080/VisaDocUpload/historycon/selectbycount/0/10");

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray jarray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("array");
for(int i=0;i<jarray.length();i++)
{
//exec your code here

}
```

I'm not sure this works imageupload: false without quotes.